# Changing/Adding Bootstrap dropdown menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Day 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Day 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Day 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

For the above snippet , I want to add the drop down menu options from Day 1 to Day 38.(Currently it has three drop down options Day 1,Day2 and Day3).I would really appreciate if some one could point out a sleek way through jQuery to do so .(Very new to jQuery). The class dropdown is from bootstrap.

Comment: Not clear at all what you mean by *" add the drop down menu options"*. Please read [ask] and be far more specific about your problem as well as showing what you have tried to solve it

Comment: Edited the question. I want to populate the options using a loop or something similar through jQuery.Since, writing all options right from Day1 to Day 38 would not be feasible.

Comment: Again... *what have you tried*? This isn't a code writing service. You are expected to make your own attempts and do your own basic research and provide code that isn't working as expected when you have problems

Comment: Cant you use a server side loop to render this html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dropdown you would just use a `select` and probably want to give it a name, id or at least a class:

```
<select name='day'></select>
```

Try this jQuery:

```
for(var i = 1; i<=36; i++) {
    $('<option>').text('Day '+i).appendTo('select[name=day]');
}
```

Not sure why you were using a `ul` with `li`/`a`. If you want a drop down, use `select`.

Make sure your script is run **after** the select is in the dom. You can either place the script lower on the page or wrap it in an ready event like:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i = 1; i<=36; i++) {
        $('<option>').text('Day '+i).appendTo('select[name=day]');
    }
});
```